# PowerShell Remove path from Select-String Output using a variable

Tags: powershell, batch-file, login-script, user-tracking, select-string

First of all, I want to apologize.  I do not work with Powershell.  This was a great learning experience for me!  If my code makes you cringe, I am sorry :)

I work with multiple buildings, Sometimes it is difficult to tell where a user is and it would be nice to search to see where the user has logged in today.

I am using a batch script when users log in to save to a file so that I can search it when a trouble ticket is submitted, but the computer machine or even the building is not included.  A new file will be generated automatically on each day.

This is the logon batch script tied as a GPO:

```
 echo User: , %username% , Computer: , %computername% , Date\Time: , %date% %time% >> \\path\to\my\saved\file-%date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%.csv
```

This is the powershell script I am using to search for the user:

```
Set-StrictMode -Version latest 

$path = '\\path\to\my\saved\'
$ext='.csv'
$file='file'
$realFile="$path$file-$(get-date -F 'yyyyMMdd')$ext"
$control = Read-Host -Prompt 'Which User are you looking for?'
$output = $path + "\output.log"
$CSV2String  = Select-String -Pattern $control -Path $realFile

Function getStringMatch 
{     
      $result = Select-String -Pattern $control -Path $realFile -Quiet 
      If ($result -eq $True) 
      { 
        $match = $realFile
        Clear-Host
        Write-Host "Success!  $control found logged in today!" -Foregroundcolor "green"
        ForEach ($line in $CSV2String) {  
        $text = $line -Split ","
        ForEach($string in $text) { 
        Write-Host "$string" 
            } 
        }
        Select-String -Pattern $control -Path $realFile | Out-File $output -Append 
      } ElseIf ($result -eq $False){
        Clear-Host
        Write-Host "Error $control not found logged in, please check the User Name and try again!" -ForegroundColor "red"
        Write-Host "'$control' Not logged in!" -ForegroundColor "yellow"
      } 
} 

getStringMatch
```

This seems to work great, however when I use the script the output looks weird to me, it displays the path to the file it has searched, I don't want that.  I just want the output of the information.

```
Success!  SearchedUser found logged in today!
\\path\to\my\saved\file-20160209.csv:1:User:
 SearchedUser
 Computer:
 MyComputer-01
 Date\Time:
 Tue 02/09/2016  9:31:41.93
```

How do I remove the "\path\to\my\saved\file-20160209.csv:1:" portion from my output?  I need it to change based on the day as well, I would like to use a variable if possible.

I played with the -Replace but I was not able to get it to accomplish the task I wanted.

Any assistance would be appreciated :)

Comment: I wanted to include finished script :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call:

```
$CSV2String  = Select-String -Pattern $control -Path $realFile
```

it returns an array of MatchInfo objects. Currently, you are calling Split on the MatchInfo's default output format (which contains the concatenation of the MatchInfo's properties: Path:LineNumber:Line). Each MatchInfo object has a Line property that contains only the line of text that was matched. So you can change your code to something like:

```
ForEach ($line in $CSV2String) 
{  
    $text = $line.Line -Split ","
```

Comment: Well that was easy :)

Thank you, that definitely helps!

It worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Not an Answer, just sharing my finished script, do with it what you please!

Completed Working script:
*edit* slight change to output.log  I made it look the same as the powershell output, I may change it again if someone has a better idea.
*edit 2* took out some secret bits I left in on accident ;)

```
###########################################################  
# AUTHOR  : Jaymes Driver  
# DATE    : 02-08-2016   
# COMMENT : Second part to log on script.
#           Search the "log" file for instance of user 
#           output which machine user is logged into. 
########################################################### 

#ERROR REPORTING ALL 
Set-StrictMode -Version latest 

#Set Path for the reference file
$path = '\\Path\To\My\'
$ext = '.csv'
$file = 'file'
$realFile = "$path$file-$(get-date -F 'yyyyMMdd')$ext"
$control = Read-Host -Prompt 'Which User are you looking for?'
$output = $path + "\output.log"

Function getStringMatch 
{     
    #-Quiet returns a True/False Value, we want to make sure the result is true!
    $result = Select-String -Pattern $control -Path $realFile -Quiet 

    If ($result -eq $True) { 
        $match = $realFile
        #Moved CSV2String here so in the future if file check is added, errors are not thrown
        $CSV2String = Select-String -Pattern $control -Path $realFile
        #Clear the screen for easier to read output
        Clear-Host
        Write-Host "Success!  '$control' found logged in today!" -Foregroundcolor "green"
        #for every instance we find do the following
            ForEach ($line in $CSV2String) { 
            # use below code if you need to replace any spaces in the data of csv file 
            #$line = $line.text - Replace " ", ""
            #Split the outputs
            $text = $line.Line -Split ","
            #For every output, write it
                ForEach($string in $text) { 
                Write-Host "$string" 
                } 
            }
        #Write the successful search to the log
        ForEach($string in $text) {
        $string | Out-File $output -Append 
        }
        #If the value is false, then what?
    } ElseIf ($result -eq $False){
        Clear-Host
        #Clear the screen so its easier to read the output
        Write-Host "Error '$control' not found logged in, please check the User Name and try again!" -ForegroundColor "red"
        Write-Host "'$control' Not found to be logged in!" -ForegroundColor "yellow"
      } 
} 


#Do the darn thing!
getStringMatch
```